# Don't process already processed files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

In our system, we have multiple pig scripts that run against a particular HDFS directory.  The pig scripts can run at different times, and are scheduled to run regularly.

Is there a way to point a pig script at the same directory for multiple executions, but make sure that it only processed new files that it hasn't seen before?

I was thinking of using a custom PathFilter for my loader, but I thought I would ask to see if there is already a way to do this, rather than me reinventing the wheel (!).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Moving files to a processed directory when the processing finished.

Comment: Hi @shazin - no, since I don't want to move the file before all the pig scripts have had a change to process it.  What I was hoping for is that each pig script would only process files it hadn't seen before, making them independent.

Comment: Change your pig scripts to pick up files from different directories based on their processing. Like Pig Script 1 will pickup from Pig 1 directory and after processing move to Pig 2 directory from which Pig Script 2 will process and move to Pig 3 directory and so forth. This way you can isolate and process files independently.